# Session Goes Null After response.redirect from Facebook in Windows Server 2012

Tags: facebook, session, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, response.redirect

This below methods are working fine in Windows server 2008 R2 and my app is registered. but when i deploy it on live server 2012 R2. Then after response.redirect my session went empty. Please help me.. because i am finding solution form couple of days but did not find any thing.
i have used the response.redirect over load method also but use less. i have compare the IIS setting of both servers (2008 r2 and 2012) but no progress. Please help me out.

```
    public ActionResult Index_Post(string txtMsg)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();

        var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {

            client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppId"],

            redirect_uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:url"],

            response_type = "code",

            scope = "email,publish_actions,publish_stream,manage_pages,read_insights,read_stream" // Add other permissions as needed

        });

        TempData["messages"] = txtMsg;

        Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);


        return View();
    }


         public static string RefreshTokenAndPostToFacebook(string currentAccessToken, string heading, string Url = "", string description = "")
    {
        string newAccessToken = RefreshAccessToken(currentAccessToken);

        PostToFacebook(newAccessToken, heading, Url, description);
        return newAccessToken; // replace current access token with this
    }



    public static string RefreshAccessToken(string currentAccessToken)
    {
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
        Dictionary<string, object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        fbParams["client_id"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppId"];
        fbParams["grant_type"] = "fb_exchange_token";
        fbParams["client_secret"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppSecret"];
        fbParams["fb_exchange_token"] = currentAccessToken;
        JsonObject publishedResponse = fbClient.Get("/oauth/access_token", fbParams) as JsonObject;
        return publishedResponse["access_token"].ToString();
    }




   public static void PostToFacebook(string pageAccessToken, string heading, string Url = "", string description = "")
    {
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);
        fbClient.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppId"];
        fbClient.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppSecret"];
        Dictionary<string, object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        fbParams["message"] = heading + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + Url;            
        var pageid = "/me/feed";
        var publishedResponse = fbClient.Post(pageid, fbParams);
    }




      public ActionResult FaceBookData()
    {

        if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
        {

            string accessCode = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();

            var fb = new FacebookClient();

            // throws OAuthException
            dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
            {

                client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppId"],

                client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppSecret"],

                redirect_uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:url"],

                code = accessCode

            });

            var accessToken = result.access_token;

            try
            {
                RefreshTokenAndPostToFacebook(accessToken, TempData["messages"].ToString(),
                    "");
                return RedirectToAction("PlayerMyLocker", "Player", new { share = "1" });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("PlayerMyLocker", "Player", new { share = ex });
                               }

        }
        else
        {

            return RedirectToAction("AcademyDescription","Academy",new{id=0});
        }
    }
```

Comment: please remove the commented codes to avoid confusion :)

Comment: Hello Khaki... i have remove my the commented lines from the code

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever figure the problem?